# Is there any hardware which converts out of range floating-point to non-zero/min/max integer?

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, hardware

While working with [Berkeley TestFloat](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/TestFloat.html) I've noticed that testing of floating-point to integer conversion is done by checking (in particular) a specific result values:

```
// file: test_a_f32_z_i32_rx.c
// function: test_a_f32_z_i32_rx
        ...
        if ( (trueZ != subjZ) || (trueFlags != subjFlags) ) {
            if (
                   verCases_checkInvInts
                || (trueFlags != softfloat_flag_invalid)
                || (subjFlags != softfloat_flag_invalid)
                || ((subjZ != 0x7FFFFFFF) && (subjZ != -0x7FFFFFFF - 1)
                        && (! f32_isNaN( genCases_f32_a ) || (subjZ != 0)))
            ) {
                ++verCases_errorCount;
```

Here we see the specific result values: `0`, `0x7FFFFFFF` (max. signed integer), `-0x7FFFFFFF - 1` (min. signed integer).

However, per C11 (and higher) standard conversion of out of range floating-point to integer leads to UB. Since usually `(int)f` leads to generation of hardware instruction (e.g. `cvttss2si` for x86_64), I wonder: is there any hardware which converts out of range floating-point to non-zero/min/max integer?

---

Extra: [Why converting 'out of range integer to integer' leads to IB, but converting 'out of range floating-point to integer' leads to UB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66589100/1778275)

Comment: Re: "Not sure what you are asking": is there any hardware which does _not_ return the smallest / largest integer, nor `0`? For example, `-6`.

Comment: OK. 1) Re: "non-IEEE hardware traps": IEEE 754 has so-called "Alternate exception handling" and, as I understand, permits trapping: "NOTE 2 — Immediate alternate exception handling for an exception can be implemented by traps". 2) FYI: if such trap will return `-6` (for example), then Berkeley TestFloat will report false positives.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any hardware which converts out of range floating-point to non-zero/min/max integer?

A note about what is *out-of-range*.

C specifies floating-point to integer conversion as the conversion of the *truncated* floating point value.

For converting to a 32-bit integer, the valid range is slightly more than [-2,147,483,648.0 ... 2,147,483,647.0].  It is (-2,147,483,649.0 ... 2,147,483,648.0).  Note the `()` versus `[]`.

---

Sample code to test a `float` before conversion. It takes advantage that `INT_MIN` is always a - power-of-2 (C23) and that `INT_MAX` is a [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html).

```
#define FLT_INT_MIN INT_MIN
#define FLT_INT_MAX_PLUS1 ((INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f)

bool float_to_int_range_test(float f) {
  return isgreater(f - FLT_INT_MIN, -1) && 
      isless(f, FLT_INT_MAX_PLUS1);
}
```

Comment: A good note, thanks. Re: "slightly more than ...": exactly. In my FP tests (still unfinished) there are macros like `F2I_FMAX` and `F2I_FMIN`, which specify the max and min FP values, for which the behavior of the conversion to integer is well-defined by the C standard.

Comment: OK. Consider addressing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77081238/1778275) question.

Comment: Consider addressing / commenting on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77060052/1778275) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard, from C11 onward, treats converting out-of-range floating-point values to integers as undefined behavior (UB). This means compilers aren't bound to specific behavior, aiming to prevent cross-platform issues. While some hardware might handle such conversions uniquely, this isn't standardized or common. The Berkeley TestFloat framework tests compliance with standards, using specific values for testing, but these may not reflect all hardware behavior. Prioritizing portability, follow the C standard's rules and avoid assumptions about hardware behavior. Handle out-of-range cases explicitly or use library functions like isfinite to ensure well-defined behavior before conversions.