# Is it possible to implement IEEE 754 conforming floating-point arithmetic based on ARM pseudocode using finite precision floating-point arithmetic?

Tags: floating-point, arm, precision, arbitrary-precision, fpu

Background: usually floating-point arithmetic is implemented using integer arithmetic (for example, Berkeley SoftFloat). Per ARM pseudocode [1] floating-point arithmetic is implemented using infinite precision floating-point arithmetic (type `real`).

My 32-bit floating-point arithmetic's model is written in C and is based on ARM pseudocode. The type `real` is implemented using finite precision floating-point arithmetic: 64-bit `double` or 80-bit `long double` (on x86_64) or 128-bit `long double` (on AArch64):

```
typedef double Real;
//typedef long double Real;
```

While testing it I've noticed some failures: most fully related to missing `Inexact` and / or `Underflow` exceptions. In some cases result is +/-1 bit off.

Background: in contrast with integer arithmetic based implementations (which check for certain bits to be non-zeros), ARM pseudocode function `FPRoundBase` computes `error`:

```
// Get the unrounded mantissa as an integer, and the "units in last place" rounding error.
int_mant = RoundDown(mantissa * 2.0^F);  // < 2.0^F if biased_exp == 0, >= 2.0^F if not
error = mantissa * 2.0^F - Real(int_mant);
```

Raising of `Inexact` and / or `Underflow` exceptions depends on this `error`:

```
if !altfp && biased_exp == 0 && (error != 0.0 || trapped_UF) then
    if fpexc then FPProcessException(FPExc_Underflow, fpcr);
...
if error != 0.0 then
    if fpexc then FPProcessException(FPExc_Inexact, fpcr);
```

My problem: in some cases, the `error` is zero, while it is expected to be non-zero, leading to missing `Inexact` and / or `Underflow` exceptions. Note that, however, the numeric result is correct in these cases. Here is an example for `x + y`:

```
x                        -4.96411207e-35         0x8683f7ff
y                        -3.98828101             0xc07f3fff
x after FPUnpack         -4.9641120695506692e-35 0xb8d07effe0000000
y after FPUnpack         -3.9882810115814209     0xc00fe7ffe0000000
x+y                      -3.9882810115814209     0xc00fe7ffe0000000
=== FPRoundBase ===
op                       -3.9882810115814209     0xc00fe7ffe0000000 
exponent                 1
min_exp                  -126
biased_exp               128
int_mant                 16728063
mantissa                 1.9941405057907104      0x3fffe7ffe0000000
frac_size                23
error                    0                       0x0
===
```

Here we see that `error` is zero, while it is expected to be non-zero.

If we multiply `1.9941405057907104` to `2^23` we will get `16728062.9999999995871232`, which is rounded to `16728063`, and `16728063 - 16728063` is `0`.

I've tried to locally increase precision when computing `error`: some failures fixed, new failures appeared. I've also tried some other "quirks and tweaks" with the same result: some failures fixed, new failures appeared.

Note that all the operations on `Real` (i.e. `double`) are done using `FE_TONEAREST`.

Finally, I've started thinking: is it possible to implement IEEE 754 conforming 32-bit (for example) floating-point arithmetic based on ARM pseudocode using finite precision floating-point arithmetic?

[1] [Exploration Tools](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/exploration-tools) (section "Arm A64 Instruction Set Architecture", button "Download XML"), file `ISA_A64_xml_A_profile-2023-03/ISA_A64_xml_A_profile-2023-03/xhtml/shared_pseudocode.html`.

---

UPD0. I've noticed that 128-bit `long double` leads to 50% less failures than 64-bit `double`.

UPD1. The "error free" means "IEEE 754 conforming". Changed to "IEEE 754 conforming".

Comment: Please define what you mean by 'error free'.  Any general operation can take a value out of range of the precision of either floating point or fixed point values.  To be 'error free' in the aspect I think you mean, you need [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), where the size of an element has a variable size (which is ironically what you have tagged this question with).  Also interesting is the [taxonomy of sorts](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/logics.shtml).  Rationals can be 'error free' for many problems.

Comment: obviously the logic uses fixed point, how else could that work.  are you saying that you are unable to select the rounding mode you want in order to get the "right answer"?  what rounding mode do you want? and what rounding mode are you seeing in your experiments?

Comment: @artlessnoise Defined. See UPD1. Re: "arbitrary precision, etc": thanks! See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/):

```
typedef mpfr_t          Real;
```

[Tests](http://www.jhauser.us/arithmetic/TestFloat.html) show that:

- it is possible to implement IEEE 754 conforming 32-bit (for example) floating-point arithmetic based on ARM pseudocode using finite precision floating-point arithmetic;
- for each FP operation the minimum MPFR precision, which leads to reaching "IEEE 754 conforming" property, is different. Examples to be added.

---

UPD0: Using the tests above I've found the following minimum MPFR precisions:

```
ADD     277
SUB     277
MUL     48
DIV     48
D2F     53
FMA     426
```

Note: due to unexhaustive tests these numbers can be higher. I cannot explain these numbers. I've found one correlation with the "Expand-and-Sum Solution" from [Secure and Accurate Summation of Many Floating-Point Numbers](https://petsymposium.org/popets/2023/popets-2023-0090.pdf):

> Single: a single-precision floating-point number has 1 sign bit,
> an 8-bit exponent, and a 23-bit mantissa. Thus, representing
> this as an integer requires 1 + 28 + 23 = 280 bits.

Notes:

1. Does it mean that per the "Expand-and-Sum Solution" the FMA requires 280 * 2 = 560 bits?
2. As I understand, the "Expand-and-Sum Solution" is not the same as "ARM pseudocode solution". The former one uses integer arithmetic, the latter one uses floating-point arithmetic.