# Conversion: out of range integer to integer vs. out of range floating-point to integer: IB vs. UB: why no consistency in behavior?

Tags: c, type-conversion, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, behavior

```
signed char c1 = 128;    //case 1: leads to IB
signed char c2 = 128.0f; //case 2: leads to UB
```

Questions:

1. Why there is no consistency in behavior? The scenarios are the same, except the source type (`int` vs. `float`).
2. What it the rationale for UB here? Why not IB as in `case 1`?

Note: this is the follow-up question for:

1. [Type casting: double to char: multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682244/type-casting-double-to-char-multiple-questions)
2. [Assigning an unsigned value to a signed char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66520556/assigning-an-unsigned-value-to-a-signed-char)

Comment: Is this the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589100/why-converting-out-of-range-integer-to-integer-leads-to-ib-but-converting-ou) previously asked?

Comment: @WeatherVane Even if it is, I think that question was closed incorrectly.

Comment: Your question can be generalised as "why some things are implementation-defined while others are undefined?" - I doubt it's reasonably answerable. It's mainly because of history, and based on the implementations, behaviours of hardware, etc when C was standardized. So "consistency" wasn't possible/practical (it's not like the committee decided to arbitrarily classify certain behaviours as IB, UB, or unspecified).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66589100/why-converting-out-of-range-integer-to-integer-leads-to-ib-but-converting-ou) was closed, however, the question was _not_ about the definition of IB/UB. The question was about the rationale of the absence of the consistency. I've had to make a new question with code sample hoping that this one will not be closed.

Comment: @P.P Thanks, interesting. Yes, it seems _because of history_. However, I've thought that ensuring (providing) the consistency in behavior is one of the most important things while designing a language. Meaning that as soon as you've memorized the behavior for some scenario involving one source type (e.g. `int`), you can be sure that the same behavior applies for the same scenario involving another source type (e.g. `float`). Otherwise (in case of no consistency), for this scenario you have to remember the exact behavior for each source type. Which is somehow tiresome.

Comment: @pmor the point is that C evolved, and at first there was no standard. Like life, technology is not pure, simple or always rational.

Comment: From the point of view of the Standard, the only difference between Implementation-Defined Behavior and Undefined Behavior is whether implementations would be required to document the behavior *even in cases where assuring any kind of remotely-predictable behavior would be expensive and useless*.  Some compiler writers behave as though there's a huge difference between the two constructs, but the Standard was never intended to discourage compiler writers from documenting and upholding useful behavioral guarantees when practical.